# How to display log for Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have a rails app and I would like to display the log in the app itself. This will allow administrators to see what changes were recently made without entering the console and using the file with the logs. All logs will be displayed in the application administration. How is it possible to implement and what kind of gems do I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a Gem.

Add a controller, read the logfiles and render the output in HTML.
Probably need to limit the number of lines you read. Also there might be different log files to chose from.

I don't think this is a good idea though. Log files are for finding errors and you should not need them in your day to day work, unless you manage ther server. 
Also they might contain sensitive data (CC Numbers, Pwds, ...) and it might get complicated when you use multiple servers with local disks.

Probably better to look at dedicated tools for this and handle logs outside of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have `git` associated with your application or git bash installed in your system.

For displaying log information for the development mode, migrate to your application folder in your console/terminal and type `tail -f log/development.log`